# MS Access Tag property - how its identifying update and insert operation?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I trying to create Add,update,Delete operation on MS Access form.I found this code on internet where Insert and update is happening on the same button. I am not getting what is exactly happening in below line and how it's identifying it is for update or insert.

Not getting following line : = Me.txtid.Tag & "" = ""

Please find below code which works perfect as per requirement.

'When we click on button Add there are two options

```
'1. for insert
'2. for update

If Me.txtid.Tag & "" = "" Then
    ' this is for insert new
    ' add data in table

CurrentDb.Execute "insert into student(stdid,stdname,gender,phone,address)" & _
    " values(" & Me.txtid & ",' " & Me.txtname & " ',' " & Me.cmbgender & " ','" & _
     Me.txtphone & "', '" & Me.txtaddress & "')"
 'refresh data in list on form
subform_student.Form.Requery
```

Else

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE student " & _
    " set stdid = " & Me.txtid & _
    ", stdname = '" & Me.txtname & "' " & _
    ", gender = '" & Me.cmbgender & " ' " & _
    ", phone = ' " & Me.txtphone & " ' " & _
    ", address = ' " & Me.txtphone & " ' " & _
    " WHERE stdid = " & Me.txtid.Tag
```

End If

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [.Tag property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196472.aspx) is a general-purpose string property of every form and control object in VBA/VB6. It is provided as a place for developers to "put stuff" to support the operation of their applications.

The original code from which you copied your sample must have written a value to `Me.txtid.Tag` when the record was loaded (e.g., perhaps in the form's `Current` event) to indicate whether the record is an existing record or a new record (empty="new", non-empty="existing"). The line

```vbs
If Me.txtid.Tag & "" = "" Then
```

simply checks to see if the `.Tag` property is empty, and then performs the INSERT or UPDATE accordingly.

BTW, re:

> below code which works perfect as per requirement

No, it doesn't. Try adding a record where [stdname] is `Tam O'Shanter` and see for yourself. You should ditch the *dynamic SQL* and use one of

- a bound form (as Gustav suggests),
- a parameterized query, or
- a recordset update.

Comment: Answer is totally convincing. Appreciate your reply :)

Answer (score 3):

Forget/remove all this code and *bind* the form to table Student to make this all happen automatically.

If *a bound form* is not familiar to you, browse for a tutorial for "Beginning with Microsoft Access" or the like.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your response about Me.txtid.Tag & "" = "" line of code?

Comment: See answer from Gord.